# checklist-model ng-repeat on checkbox

Tags: angularjs

Checkbox is not updating while

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-repeat="status in statuses" 
       checklist-model="task.status" 
       checklist-value="status">
```

In [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/omWJYP5E0CU6jwFLs01X?p=preview)
Isn't that 2 and 3(in plunker) are similar? Any Idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `ng-repeat` on the INPUT tag. You should put INPUT inside the `ng-repeat`. The `checklist-model` directive should have a separate scope.

Answer (score 0):

All the official document [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebv3p/2/)  to use it within label. And my guess is that, the statement

```
<input type="checkbox"
       checklist-model="task.status" 
       checklist-value="status">
```

is an iterating one. And if you add another iteration to it(ng-repeat) to it, it doesn't look logical.